# Stanford NER custom model accuracy testing

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am working on Entity extraction using a custom model. I trained my CRF based model on a large dataset as

> **java -Xmx16g stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop ner.prop**

using these features

**Property file (ner.prop)**

```
 trainFile = training_data_IOB.tsv
 #serializeTo = ner-model.ser.gz
 map = word=0,answer=1

 useClassFeature=true
 useWord=true
 qnSize=10
 entitySubclassification=IOB1
 retainEntitySubclassification=true
 mergeTags=true
 useNGrams=true
 noMidNGrams=true
 maxNGramLeng=6
 usePrev=true
 useNext=true
 useSequences=true
 usePrevSequences=true
 maxLeft=1
 useTypeSeqs=true
 useTypeSeqs2=true
 useTypeySequences=true
 wordShape=chris2useLC
 useDisjunctive=true
 useGazettes=true
 gazette=gazetter.txt
 sloppyGazette=true
```

**Training file (training_data_IOB.tsv)**

```
Thousands   O
of  O
demonstrators   O
have    O
marched O
through O
London  B-LOC
to  O
protest O
the O
war O
in  O
Iraq    B-LOC
...     ...
```

**Gazette file(gazetter.txt)**

```
B-LOC   Iraq
B-LOC   Afghanistan
B-ORG   Congressional
B-LOC   Bangladesh
B-LOC   Canada
B-ORG   ...
```

the new model is created as **ner-model.ser.gz** and working quite well.

> **Now my question is, How I can calculate its percentage accuracy on any unseen(new) data without any manual counting and calculations??**

I'm new in this field so kindly post a detailed descriptive answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a conll file with the gold tags for a test set you can use this command and it will output scores (this example runs our model, replace with your custom model):

```
java -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadclassifier edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -testFile testData.conll
```

Comment: what should be the format of testData.conll?? words \t original tags or space separated or anything else?

Comment: conll format, same as the training data...word + "\t" + gold

Comment: this works for the above problem but when I used POS tag as a feature in  NER Model training this command didn't didn't work on the new model? training file is like word+"\t"+NER+"\t"+POS and property file change map = word=0,answer=1,tag=2.

Comment: Did you add useTags to your properties file? https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/NERFeatureFactory.html